# Pod version still points to old cocoapods when I have newer one installed

Tags: ios, cocoapods

My `pod install` complains I'm using an outdated cocoapods version (1.7.3), even though I have a newer one installed (1.10.1). When I ran `gem list`, I could see I had two different versions installed.

So I ran `gem uninstall cocoapods` and uninstalled the outdated version, 1.7.3. Now, `pod install` just complains I'm missing the old cocoapods version (1.7.3) instead of using the newer version 1.10.1 which I still have installed. Running `bundle install` just re-installs 1.7.3 again. I also checked `pod --version` which outputs 1.7.3

Answer (score 6):

Finally, I noticed that my project's `Gemfile.lock` had the line `cocoapods-core (1.7.3)` in it. I ran `bundle update` which updated the Gemfile.lock to now have `cocoapods-core (1.10.1)`. Then, I ran `bundle install` which installed cocoapods-core 1.10.1. Now when I run `pod --version`, I get `1.10.1` as the output.

Comment: Where is the file?